# Replace all < and > that are NOT part of an HTML tag

Tags: .net, html, regex

I have been trying to work through a RegEx that I could use to replace all < and > text strings, EXCEPT for when those strings are part of an HTML tag.

For example:

```
var str = "<p>The <b>value</b> <i>1</i> is < <u>2</u></p>"
```

Given the above example, I want a resultant string that looks like this:

```
var str = "<p>The <b>value</b> <i>1</i> is &lt; <u>2</u></p>"
```

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), then consider using HTML Agility Pack instead.

Comment: lol "Parsing HTML with regex summons tainted souls into the realm of the living."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not easy.   See the authoritative answer to a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Regular expressions are not built for this type of parsing.  Even tokenizing or dom parsing can cause problems.  The title of your question illustrates the problem:

`Replace all < and > that are NOT part of an HTML tag`

How can your parser know if `< and >` is an `<AND>` tag, or simply two orphan angle brackets around the word `and`?

An HTML parser is probably your best bet, but how the orphan brackets are handled is key.  Also, you would need to look for unmatched tags or illegal tags to catch cases such as the title of your question.

Answer (score 2):

HTML is notoriously difficult to parse using regular expressions. The HTML specifications are very forgiving, and browser implementations tend to be even more forgiving. The result of this is that attempting to match something like this using regular expressions alone is almost impossible.

Its far more robust to use a full blown HTML parser that understands all the special cases to generate a DOM, and then walk through the resulting DOM in code looking for angle brackets.

As you have tagged your question with .NET I can recommend the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for performing this type of task.

Answer (score -2):

There have been several questions asked regarding how to detect text that is or is not in an HTML tag; you should be able to modify the concept to your needs.

Basically, you're looking for a `<` that is not followed by a `>`, and you want to replace it with the ampersand-notated form `&lt;`. Try something like:

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, "<(?!.*?[>])", "&lt;");
```

Comment: And what happens for the string `<img src="lessthan.jpg" alt="<">`?

Comment: This will match every `<` in the sample above; in fact, it will match every `<` up to the final `>` in the entire string. This is precisely the sort of task that makes regex the wrong tool for HTML/XML.